# Select the first three elements in CSS and repeat

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I have a list of N cards, floated, with `width:33.3333%`. When the user clicks on a card, it rotate and expands.

However, I would like that every 3:rd card started from the 1:st had a certain `margin`, every 3:rd card started from the 2:nd another `margin` and every 3:rd started from the 3:rd yet another `margin`.

Is there a way to do this with **CSS** selectors, for example child selector?

[Plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/xU8AUmlE6S0foLhZqwrJ?p=preview)

Example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body class="landing">
    <section id="intro">
      <div class="inner">
        <h2>Title</h2>
        <!-- Cards -->
        <div class="cards">
          <div class="riga">
            <div class="r2">
              <div class="r4">
                <div class="card-container manual-flip">
                  <div onclick="rotateCard(this)" class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                      <div class="cover">
                        <img src="img/rotating_card_thumb2.png" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="user">
                        <img src="img/img1.png" class="img-circle" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                          <h3 class="name">Text</h3>
                          <p class="profession">Text</p>
                          <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                          <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">
                          <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                    Info
                                                </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                      <div class="header">
                        <h5 class="motto">Text</h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                          <h4 class="text-center">Info</h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                Back  
                                            </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="r4">
                <div class="card-container manual-flip">
                  <div onclick="rotateCard(this)" class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                      <div class="cover">
                        <img src="img/rotating_card_thumb.png" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="user">
                        <img src="img/img2.png" class="img-circle" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                          <h3 class="name">Text</h3>
                          <p class="profession">Text</p>
                          <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                          <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">
                          <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                   Info
                                                </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                      <div class="header">
                        <h5 class="motto">Text</h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                          <h4 class="text-center">Info</h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                Back  
                                            </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="r4">
                <div class="card-container manual-flip">
                  <div onclick="rotateCard(this)" class="card">
                    <div class="front">
                      <div class="cover">
                        <img src="img/rotating_card_thumb2.png" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="user">
                        <img src="img/img3.png" class="img-circle" />
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                          <h3 class="name">Text</h3>
                          <p class="profession">Text</p>
                          <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                          <a onclick="rotateCard(this).disable();" class="actions button rimmed" href="#">Text</a>
                        </div>
                        <div class="footer">
                          <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                    Info
                                                </button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="back">
                      <div class="header">
                        <h5 class="motto">Text</h5>
                      </div>
                      <div class="content">
                        <div class="main">
                          <h4 class="text-center">Info</h4>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="footer">
                        <button class="btn btn-simple">
                                                Back  
                                            </button>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!-- end inner -->
    </section>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Can you show some HTML code sample for the same?

Comment: Your question is unclear at *"I would like that the first back-card had a certain margin, the second another margin and the third another margin. And then repeat for each row."*. Kindly clarify?

Comment: So what you need to do with this?

Comment: For each card, when it rotate, has a specific margin. In particular, the cards on left have X margin, the middle cards have Y margin, the cars on right have Z margin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CSS `:nth-child()`

```css
span {
  float: left;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 5px;
  width: calc(33% - 60px);
}

span:nth-child(3n+1) {
  background-color: green;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
span:nth-child(3n+2) {
  background-color: red;
  margin-left: 40px;
}
span:nth-child(3n+3) {
  background-color: blue;
  margin-left: 60px;
}
```

```html
<span>1</span>
<span>2</span>
<span>3</span>
<span>4</span>
<span>5</span>
<span>6</span>
<span>7</span>
<span>8</span>
```

Comment: Hey bud, does this really answer this question?

Comment: @PraveenKumar Hey back bud, if I understood the OP right, yes, if not, I will delete it when that will be known ... or make it work :)

Comment: Yes I mean this, but I don't know why in my example (http://plnkr.co/edit/xU8AUmlE6S0foLhZqwrJ?p=preview ) it doesn't work. If you click and rotate the card, you can see that the browser, on .back class, it recognize just :nth-child(3n+2)

Comment: What should I use instead?

Comment: Uff, it doesn't work yet. What am I doing wrong? http://plnkr.co/edit/xU8AUmlE6S0foLhZqwrJ?p=preview

Comment: @panagulis72 In your demo you use `.back: nth-child`, it should be `.hover:nth-child` ... and I rolled back my answer as I was wrong, you can use `nth-child` on a class

Comment: lol.... now it seems blocked on .nth-child(3n+1) look: http://plnkr.co/edit/xU8AUmlE6S0foLhZqwrJ?p=preview :///   maybe the nth-child is not the bestet approach in this case

Comment: @PraveenKumar I guessed right :) ... I also updated the question and voted for reopen.

Comment: @LGSon They are okay with it.

Comment: They solved the question!!! Look the update: http://plnkr.co/edit/xU8AUmlE6S0foLhZqwrJ?p=preview  we were wrong in the selector. The right css is this: .r4:nth-child(3n+1) .hover{ 
    margin-left:310px;
}
.r4:nth-child(3n+2) .hover{ 
    margin-left:8130px;
 }
.r4:nth-child(3n+3) .hover{ 
    margin-left:-500px;
 }

Comment: @panagulis72 My answer is correct and shows how to select every 3:rd element, though in your particular case and the effect you wanted, needed another solution, so please accept an answer for this question and one for the other.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you probably can.

Try this:

```
.yourclass:nth-child(3n+1){
  //child 1, 4, 7....
  margin-left:10px;
}
.yourclass:nth-child(3n+2){
   //child 2,5,8....
   margin-left:20px;
 }
.yourclass:nth-child(3n+3){
    //child 3,6,9....
    margin-left:30px;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have the following HTML and CSS you will obtain what you want:

```css
/* Global Setting for columns */
.col {
    float: left;
    text-align: center;
}

/* Different margin for columns. */
.col:nth-child(3n-2) {
 background-color: red;
    clear: left;

    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 7.5px;
    width: calc(33.33333333% - 2px - 15px); /* size + border + margin */
}
.col:nth-child(3n-1) {
 background-color: green;

    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 15px;
    width: calc(33.33333333% - 2px - 30px); /* size + border + margin */
}
.col:nth-child(3n) {
 background-color: blue;

    border: 1px solid #000;
    border-left: 0;
    border-right: 0;
    width: 33.33333333%; /* Only size */
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
 <div class="row">
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3<br>3</div>
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2<br>2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">1<br>1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
  <div class="col">1</div>
  <div class="col">2</div>
  <div class="col">3</div>
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: The problem remains: watch the comments of other answer. If I try to enter your code, it gives me the same error: on class .back remains (4n-2) for all the cards

Comment: I don't be able to offer more help without an HTML/CSS example of your problem.