# Repeat a CSS effect for the three elements of each row

Tags: css, css-selectors, css-transitions

I am doing a little user interface in which I have some elements, arranged in rows by three. These elements are floated and their width is `width:33.3333%` .So for each `row` there are 3. I do not know exactly how many will be in total as I shall call them via **json**. 
When the user clicks on an card, it rotate and expands as you can see in [THIS LIVE EXAMPLE](http://plnkr.co/edit/xU8AUmlE6S0foLhZqwrJ?p=preview). 
I would like that the first back-card had a X `margin`, the second had a Y `margin` and the third had a Z `margin`. So all different. But this attribute has to be must be repeated for all `rows`. Is there a way to do this with **CSS** selectors? I've tried with `:nth-child` but it doesn't work.

```
.hover:nth-child(3n+1){ 
 margin-left:10px;
 }
 .hover:nth-child(3n+2){ 
 margin-left:20px;
 }
.hover:nth-child(3n+3){ 
margin-left:30px;
 }
```

Comment: If this is intended to be an edit to your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35127930/select-the-first-three-elements-in-css-and-repeat), please edit your previous question. Do not repost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are applying `:nth-child` to elements that are not under the same parent.
Each `.hover` element is inside a `.r4` elements so you should do it like this:

```
.r4:nth-child(3n+1) .hover{ 
  margin-left:10px;
}
.r4:nth-child(3n+2) .hover{ 
   margin-left:20px;
 }
.r4:nth-child(3n+3) .hover{ 
   margin-left:30px;
 }
```